# what should i do to make sure 'username' unique in table user and avoid duplicate entry '*' for key 2

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I created two tables, `user` and `journey`.

In table `user`, I added a column named `username` and made it unique.

In table `journey`, I reference `user_id` (the primary key in table `user`) to `foreign key` in table `journey`.

two tabless SQL below:

```
create table user(
    user_id  INT  auto_increment  PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(50) not null,
    avator  varchar(50),
    gender  boolean not null,
    phone varchar(20),
    unique(username)
);

create table journey(
    id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    start varchar(100) not null,
    dest varchar(100) not null,
    time date not null,
    person INT,
    user_id INT not null,
    foreign key(user_id) references user(user_id)
);
```

`user` and `journey`'s relation is one-to-many

When I insert new journey data into table `journey`, hibernate always tried to insert user info into table `user`, but `username` is set to be unique, so exception occurs. I am not familiar with databases, what should I do?

Comment: Why does inserting into `journey` try to insert into `user`? When you insert into `journey`, you should supply the `user_id` of an existing user.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Updated**

First of all understand the situation why we need two unique columns instead of one.

**Single Unique Column**

Consider a scenario where each product in an inventory system has a globally unique product code assigned. In this case, a single unique column for the product code is sufficient:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
  ProductCode VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductName VARCHAR(100),
  Price DECIMAL(10, 2),
  -- Other columns...
);
```

**Two Unique Columns**

Imagine a situation where you manage a library database, and each book is uniquely identified by a combination of its ISBN (International Standard Book Number) and the edition number. Here, using two unique columns ensures uniqueness across different editions of the same book:

```
CREATE TABLE Books (
  ISBN VARCHAR(13) PRIMARY KEY,
  EditionNumber INT UNIQUE,
  Title VARCHAR(200),
  Author VARCHAR(100),
  -- Other columns...
);
```

**Merge Two Unique Columns To One**

Instead of creating two unique columns, we can create only one column by merging these two if it fulfills business requirement.

```
CREATE TABLE Books (
  ISBN_EditionNumber VARCHAR(13)  PRIMARY KEY,
  Title VARCHAR(200),
  Author VARCHAR(100),
  -- Other columns...
);
```

**Solution to MIAN's question:**

- remove the id column
- make username as unique key (say primary key)

By doing this, you will get uniqueness in your table, no more data-duplication

Comment: There's nothing wrong with two unique columns. It's very common to use an `auto_increment` column as the primary key, but you still want to prevent two users from having the same username.

Comment: @MIAN mark answer accepted if it helps you or increase your knowledge about database learning

Comment: @Barmar yes, this is common to use more than one unique keys but he needs a username unique (no duplication) so this is simply possible through making username as primary key